# GTest: Handle Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, googletest

I'm using GTest for unittesting my project.

One of the functions I want to test terminates with a Segmentation Fault, which is is not the correct behavior of this function.

I want gtest to report this error, like every other error, but it doesnt. It doesnt run other test cases and it doenst print a report at the end.

It there a way to get a correct report from gtest for this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't link any code example, so the best answer I can give you is very general.

Your problem is either:

1. Your function is incorrect and is segmentation faulting (edge cases or main body)
2. You wrote your test badly, and it (the test itself) is segmentation faulting

Seg Faulting happens when your program/test tries to do something it isn't allowed to do (i.e.. you try to dereference a null ptr, access memory that isn't yours, etc..). Google Test is not able to handle the signal SIGSEGV (nobody is), so your program will crash. Seg Faults are the operating systems way of telling you that you did something illegal and they instantly terminate your program. You need to fix the segmentation fault in order to get results. I would recommend doing the following things:

1. Learn how to use GDB, and run your program in GDB to figure out where it is segmentation faulting
2. Use print statements to figure out where your program is segmentation faulting.

Comment: Maybe my question was not clear enough. In this case I know where the error is, but my problem is, that one segfault prevents that I get an gtest result. I hope that gtest has a smart feature which allows to run alle other tests and report this one as failing with segfault.

Comment: A Seg Fault kills the executable, so Google Test is no longer running after it occurs (and can't do anything about it). I would recommend that you break your tests up into multiple executables, and have your CI job search the output for failures, and fail the pipeline if a seg fault occurs.  The only real way to have some of your tests still produce results is to split up your executable into multiple executables, and hope they don't all seg fault. If they all Seg Fault, you will never get GTest's normal end of run output.

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: Not really, my goal was to get full gtest results, and I don't understand why googletest can to death tests, but can't handle segfaults.